# Django Template Logic To Add Time To Timestamp Variable?

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got a field on an object, 'timestamp' which looks like this in the database:

```
2012-03-18 12:47:01
```

I'm trying to write a condition into my Django template that looks at two objects' timestamps, and compares them. Essentially, what I'm looking for is this..

```
If objectB.timestamp > objectA.timestamp + 10 minutes
    do whatever
else
    do something else
```

The problem I'm running into is I can't add to the timestamp. Any thoughts? I tried truncating the time, but that works from the backside. I tried cutting out digits and truncating, but that's not really a working solution. Any thoughts?

Is there a way to truncate from the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be custom tag or filter. For adding and subtracting datetimes use [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).